Is who or whom correct in this sentence and why?
This is the sentence:
I help writers improve and refine their tone and pacing according to where their books will be published and who their target audience contains.
Is who or whom more accurate here?

"who their target audience is" would be much more idiomatic English. And avoid this problem. "Is/was" is overwhelmingly the most common verb to follow "target audience".


According to is shown as a [compound] preposition in all four American unabridged dictionaries MW3, RHU, Encarta, and AHD. [BUT] The
Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL) classifies according
as a preposition with to phrase as its complement, noting that the
meaning when used as a preposition differs from the meaning of the
"-ing" form of the verb accord.

[Wiktionary]
However, here we have clauses (traditional analysis):

according to where their books will be published
according to who/m their target audience contains.

In this case, the rules 'prepositional complements take the objective case' and 'objects take the objective case in formal language' ('... their audience contains these people. / whom?) happily coincide.
With '... according to who[m]ever wrote this' there is conflict, and the modern advice 'go with who rather than whom in most cases) is probably best adhered to.

CGEL classifies relative "where" as a preposition that occurs as head of a PP functioning as a fused relative construction. On that analysis, "where their books will be published" is a PP with "where" as locative adjunct.

"Who the audience contains" seems to be the core construction, and that to me calls for "who". An alternate phrasing could be "...according to whom the book is directed". Or to show another contrast, "Who is the audience hearing?" vs. "From whom is the audience gaining knowledge?" I'm sorry to say I don't understand many newer syntactical terms, but I get subject vs. object.

With 'Let him/he who is without sin cast the first stone', the 'correct' answer is traditionally 'Let him ...'. But more people use 'he' here.
